# How to return time if not found in the booking table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table rooms contain all information booking and i want return booking time(startTime and endTime) to User based on the user's input.

Rooms:

```
ID   Name    Type  StartTime  EndTime
01    Room01  1     8:00:00     8:30:00
02   Room02   2     9:00:00     9:30:00
01    Room01  1     9:00:00     9:30:00
02   Room02   2     10:00:00     9:00:00
01    Room01  1     11:00:00     11:30:00
02   Room02   2     13:00:00     13:30:00
```

**Case1**: If customer want booking **startTime: 8:00:00** and booking in duration : **30 minutes(EndTime : 8:30:00)**. In my database, because booking Room01 has booking, Room 02 not booking in range time. I want postgres return is : 
**Room02   StartTime: 8:00:00 and EndTime: 8:30:00**

**Case2:** If customer want booking **startTime: 5:00:00** and booking in duration : 30 minutes(**EndTime : 5:30:00**). In my database, because  two room free. I want postgres return Room01 or Room02  : 
**Room01   StartTime: 5:00:00 and EndTime: 5:30:00**

**Case3:** If customer want booking **startTime: 9:00:00** and booking in duration : 30 minutes(**EndTime : 9:30:00**). In my database, because  Room01 and Room02 has booking. I want postgres return time closest to user booking time. Looking in my database, Postgres should return is:
**Room01   StartTime: 9:30:00 and EndTime: 10:00:00(Room2 free but not closest to user booking time)**

How to do that in postgres sql. I have encountered this problem for nearly 3 days but have yet to find the optimal plan. Please help

Comment: To solve case1 and case2, checkout the `OVERLAPS` operator in postgresql. The third case is a functional requirement and that is not something that we do on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks you for help. But i have a question.
In case 3, can you show me a way to solve it? In case 1 and 2 I am understanding that I will use the overlap operator to check the time of booking customers and the time in the database. If the operator returns false, I will return the input time.

Comment: Correct about case1 and case2. When it comes to case 3, there are multiple ways in which you can handle it. You can generate the next time interval (in your app) and check if you can book that one. You could also fetch the next N available slots from time X and book the first one.